# Editing Wordpress code to bring post type

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to edit the following so that rather than bringing in the most recent posts, it bring in posts from a specific category?

```html
if( !function_exists('zolo_recent_posts') ) { function zolo_recent_posts($atts, $content = null) { ob_start(); extract(shortcode_atts(array( "num" => '4', 'columnsizepost' => '', 'data_animation'=>'fadeInDown', 'data_delay'=>'0' ), $atts)); global $post;
query_posts( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page='.$num.'&paged='. @$paged ); ?>

<div class="zolo-recent-post <?php echo $columnsizepost;?>">
  <?php $i=1 ; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
  <?php //$image=w p_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'recent_posts_thumb' ); ?>
  <?php endif; if( $i % 4==0 ) $class='last' ; else $class='' ; ?>
  <div class="blog-box <?php echo $class;?> animated hiding" data-animation="<?php echo $data_animation;?>" data-delay="<?php echo $data_delay; ?>">
    <div class="blog-img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('recent_posts_thumb');
    }
    else {
        echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/thumb-img.jpg" />';
    }
    ?>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-text-area">
      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a></h3>
      <div class="alltag-row"> <span class="date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
        <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
        </span>  <span class="add-comment"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#hello">
        <?php comments_number( '0 <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>', '1 <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>', '% <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>' ); ?>
        </a></span> 
      </div>
      <?php the_excerpt() ;?>
    </div>
  </div>
  </span>
  <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); $demolp_output=o b_get_clean(); return $demolp_output; } add_shortcode( "zolo_recent_post", "zolo_recent_posts"); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=CATEGORYNAME&showposts=5');
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  // do whatever you want
?>
<b><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php      the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
 endwhile;
 ?>
```

Using this way you can fetch posts of a specific category in WordPress.

Comment: Of course.. can't see the woods for the trees sometimes. Thanks.